# #use "str.cma" and #use "name.mli" in Eclipse

Tags: ocaml

How do I use "str.cma" in Eclipse?

Also, how do I link name.ml to name.mli? I would usually do #use "name.mli" in "name.ml" when using Emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#use` is not emacs specific, and is not even OCaml language specific. It is a directive of a program called toplevel, or in a more common parlance an interpreter. So, your premises is wrong, that you can do this in Emacs. What concerning Eclipse (I suspect, that you're trying to use OCaIDE), then there're lots of [tutorials](http://www.algo-prog.info/ocaide/tutorials/3-projects/projects.htm) and online help, that explains how to add dependencies to a project.